# spring boot jar doesn't work with -cp option

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin

I have always created uber jar with spring-boot and used `java -jar springboot.jar` command to start container. Now my requirement is changed and I need to point to external classpath as follows which is not fixed. I still create uber jar for spring boot.
`java -Dprofile=dev -cp springboot.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/local/hbase/lib/* com.myapp.Application`

It throws following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncConfigurer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 13 more
```

My Application class uses org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurer

Here's maven:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeGroupIds>org.apache.hadoop,org.apache.hbase</excludeGroupIds>
                    <excludeArtifactIds>hadoop-yarn-common,hadoop-yarn-client,hadoop-annotations,hadoop-yarn-api,hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient,
                    hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle,hadoop-mapreduce-client-app,hadoop-mapreduce-client-core,hadoop-mapreduce-client-common,
                    hadoop-yarn-server-common,hadoop-hdfs,hadoop-auth,hadoop-common,parquet-hadoop,hadoop-client</excludeArtifactIds>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.myApp.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Build-Scm-Branch>${scmBranch}</Build-Scm-Branch>
                            <Build-Revision-Number>${buildNumber}</Build-Revision-Number>
                            <Timestamp>${timestamp}</Timestamp>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

One thing I notice that spring-boot-maven-plugin keeps all the uber jars inside lib folder instead of extracting every class in put it in flat hierarchy like shade plugin. I don't know if that's the reason -cp is not recognizing any uber classes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the PropertiesLauncher by setting the `<layout>ZIP</laout>` for the spring-boot-maven-plugin, you can extend your classpath using the loader.path property. E.g.:

```
java -Dprofile=dev -Dloader.path=springboot.jar,/usr/local/hadoop/lib,/usr/local/hbase/lib -jar springboot.jar
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-property-launcher-features in spring boots reference guide.

Comment: This will only work if Spring Boot's `PropertiesLauncher` is used, which probably won't be the case since the OP is building a JAR. You have to specify `<layout>ZIP</layout>` in the configuration of `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to make the plugin use the `PropertiesLauncher`.

Comment: Thanks, @hzpz. I didn't spot it. Added in the answer.

Comment: I logged a bug for load.path issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3685